# How to force-refresh browser cache automatically for each React App deployment in 2022?

Tags: reactjs

By default, when a React Application is deployed, the cached version will display, even if changes were made in the new build. This requires the end user to hard-refresh their page (`Ctrl+F5`) to see new changes. It is not feasible to have a user do this each time.

With the constant upgrades and speed of software evolving, there are many different ways to accomplish this. However, the answers widely vary due to different practices being used each year.

What is the best practice to accomplish this in 2022? Is there a short and easy way to do this?

Edit: I am using the create-react-app project template.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with broswer caching the old pages and not React, to avoid this you need to either force refresh as you mentioned or changing your build strategy with some sort of different file naming, this can be done by using webpack caching here https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/.

This way your scripts will have different names with each new deployment and the browser will ahve to reload the new scripts when fetching the index.html.

Comment: What if this is already happening, but clients' browsers are still caching and running the old scripts?

Comment: You can try adding the HTTP beader from whatever server you are using on the response, Cache-Control no-cache
this tells the browser to always pull the site and not cache the files, or you can set expiry date of one day, etc.